# How to pass cookies between subdomains? Change cookie domain?

Tags: python, ajax, node.js, flask, subdomain

Okay so this is my current situation.

I am trying to send an ajax request to api.mysite.com from main.mysite.com. Everything is working fine but cookies are not being sent.

Based on couple hours of research, it seems like I need to change the domain of cookie.

In my case, cookie domain is main.mysite.com, and cookie domain should be .mysite.com if I want to include cookie in ajax requests.

So my question is...how do I change the cookie domain?  Or are there any other ways to do it?

My current stack is

nginx for reverse proxy |
node.js(express.js) for front end server |
python(flask) and mysql for api server |
redis for session saving

They are all running in a same box.

Comment: In both domains you have the same stack?

Comment: Use jquery on front?

Comment: front - jquery, node.js(express.js)
back - python(flask)
nginx is proxing main.mysite.com to node.js, and api.mysite.com to python

Comment: where you set cookie's? in node.js?

Comment: If you are asking where I save on server, then I am saving it on redis

Comment: "where" i mean in which system set cookie in response header ;)

Comment: using express.js, 
res.cookie("key", "value", {domain: ".mysite.com"})
but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are setting cookies. One way to this is While setting a cookie, use `domain` attribute to set a cookie wrt `.mysite.com`.

[Attributes of HTTP cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path)